# Add two variables in one line and save them in a text file

Tags: bash, shadow

I've created the following script

```
    #!/bin/bash

shdw=$(cat /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,2)
users=$(cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f3,4,5,6,7)
echo $users:$shdw >> bk.txt
```

I want it to save each user account into one line. perhaps a do while iduno

Comment: Does anyoneknow how to disable shadow passwords in linux so i dont have to do this

Comment: Don't. Every user can read /etc/shadow, and take this file home for at-his-leisure password cracking.

Comment: @DAVID, some Linux distros have pwunconv for that, but I agree with thiton that having all that info in a world readable file is a security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `join` program is your friend:

```
join -t : /etc/passwd /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f3-7,1,8
```

Comment: It saves all the accounts in one single line. ie. acc1,acc2,ac3
i want each account inits own line

Comment: @DAVID: Running just this single line in a shell, with nothing changed? I seriously doubt that. join joins only matching lines, and most certainly inserts no commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d: -f1-2 /etc/shadow > myshadow
cut -d: -f3-7 /etc/passwd > mypasswd
paste -d: mypasswd myshadow >> bk.txt
```

Comment: This will actually fail to work when passwd and shadow have a different ordering of lines. Should be a fairly rare case, but noteworthy nevertheless.

Comment: True and fair enough; caveat emptor :-)